# Getting Cancan's load_and_authorize_resource working within a custom create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Trying to set up **Cancan** within an app of mine and having trouble with my `PostsController`.

In a nutshell, when a `Post` is created I'd like it associated with the `current_user` so my create action looks something like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [:index, :show]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...
  def create
    # @post = Post.new(params[:post])   # <-- covered by load_and_authorize_resource
    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.create(params[:post])
    respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

I'm not exactly sure what `load_and_authorize_resource` is intended to do (other than the obvious). But what about in a situation like this? Do I need to override the `load_and_authorize_resource` for the create action somehow? or is there another (read: better) way to go about loading the `@user` and THEN creating the `@post`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution to your problem would be to use a nested-resource, rather than creating a custom action

Directly taken from the CanCan Wiki:

[Nested-Resources](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources)

> As of 1.4, it's also possible to nest through a method, this is
>   commonly the current_user  method.
>
> ```
>  class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
>    load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_user
>  end
> ```
>
> Here everything will be loaded through the current_user.projects association.

This should be safer as well, as loading of a post will be done through the association for other actions in your controller

Comment: What about error coming if accessing project of another user from controller. It is throwing error `Couldn't find Project with 'id'=<another_user_project_id> [WHERE `projects`.`user_id` = ?]
`

Answer (score 12):

I think the best solution, since this is a unique problem, for you to alter `load_and_authorize_resource` line to this:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create]
```

And the action to this:

```
def create
  authorize! :create, Post
  current_user.posts.create(params[:post])
end
```

Comment: Works great for me. You may add :new to :except as well.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me too

`authorize_resource class: 'User'`